# How to update the model data changed inside the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of categories that I want to edit. I can successfully pass them into the controller.

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    if (!IsAdmin) return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    ViewBag.IsAdmin = IsAdmin;
    var categories = _model.Categories.ToList();
    return View(categories);
}
```

Then I have a view to edit the names of the categories.

```
@using MyStructures.Models
@model List<MyStructures.Models.Category>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Categories", FormMethod.Post))
{
    foreach (var category in Model)
    {
        var categoryToEdit = @category;
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Category Number: @category.Id</td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => categoryToEdit.Name)</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save"
                           formaction=@Href("~/Categories/Update/") />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }

    <input type="submit" value="Cancel"
           formaction=@Href("~/Home/Index/") />
}
```

How do I pass the updated value to the "Update" controller? The value of `Category obj` is null.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(Category obj)
{
    var existing = _model.Categories.Find(obj.Id);
    existing.Name = obj.Name;
    _model.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Comment: Your model is `List<Category>` but your method parameter is `Category obj` - it would need to be `List<Category> obj` and the controls for `Category` need to be generated in a `for` loop (not `foreach`) or using an `EditorTemplate` for typeof `Category`. But why do you have multiple submit buttons in the form (one for each Category and then another one at the bottom)? What is it you actually trying to do?